# Restrict multiple login from same user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have integrated Facebook and Google login for my rails app, How do I restrict same user signing in with different account?

Comment: validate the `uniqueness` of `email` or combination of `firstname+lastname`

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer is: you can't, because you cannot be sure than you'll find the same info on both side (example: I may use one email on Facebook and another for Google, or one of them may not be public, etc).

A good guess would be to prevent creation of a user which looks "too similar" to another one using simple validations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: true # check that no one has the same email
  validates :first_name, uniqueness: { scope: :last_name } # check no double in first name + last name
...
end
```